# Selenium Error: Which webdrivermanager version supports chrome version 121?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriver-manager

Currently I'm using 5.5.2 version of webdrivermanager. Getting the below error

> Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not
> created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
> Current browser version is 121.0.6167.184 with binary path
> /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

build.gradle

```
implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '4.4.2'
implementation group: 'io.github.bonigarcia', name: 'webdrivermanager', version: '5.5.2'
```

which version of webdrivermanager supports chrome version 121?

Answer (score 3):

You will have to clear cache from `~/.cache/selenium`.

1. Use latest version of Selenium and WDM
2. Navigate to above directory and remove cached `chromedriver` and `resolution.properties`. You can even check before deleting `resolution.properties` and you might see chrome121 key value pointing to 114 version.
3. Run your tests again.

This is how your `resolution.properties` will look after above steps:

```
#WebDriverManager Resolution Cache
#Mon Feb 19 10:39:15 CET 2024
chrome=121
chrome-ttl=11\:39\:15 19/02/2024 CET
chrome121=121.0.6167.184
chrome121-ttl=10\:39\:15 20/02/2024 CET
```

It should work.

Comment: Clear the cache and updating the dependency should do the trick. Cheer !

Comment: I upgrade to selenium 4.13 and webdrivermanager to 5.6.4. I was previously using WebDriverManager.chromeDriver().setup(); now I changed it to WebDriverManager.chromeDriver().clearDriverCache().setup();

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the issue with the version of `ChromeDriver` not supporting the current Chrome version (121.0.6167.184), you should use `WebDriverManager` version 5.6.0 or higher, as it supports `ChromeDriver` version 121.

- Remove the current WebDriverManager dependency from your build.gradle file.
- Add the latest WebDriverManager dependency:

:

```
implementation group: 'io.github.bonigarcia', name: 'webdrivermanager', version: '5.6.0'
```

- Run your build script to update the dependencies.
- Verify that the updated WebDriverManager is in your project's dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the same issue by updating wdm to the latest version available for now - [5.6.3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/5.6.3)

Comment: Still getting the same error. Can you please help with your selenium version?

Comment: @GanesanM, it is 4.16.1

Comment: See my answer- after upgrading, you need to delete resolution.properties to force it to download the correct version

Comment: Getting this error now

**error: cannot access org.openqa.selenium.OutputType
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
                          ^
  bad class file: /Users/username/Library/Gradle/gradle-7.5.1/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api/4.16.1/55e13a2d43a7c174ee85152a8161e9acc101de32/selenium-api-4.16.1.jar(org/openqa/selenium/OutputType.class)
    class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.**

Comment: build.gradle
implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '4.16.1'
    implementation group: 'io.github.bonigarcia', name: 'webdrivermanager', version: '5.6.3'

Comment: @GanesanM, are you using java8? The error is caused due to a mismatch between the lib java version and your one, 52 - java8, 55 - java11

Comment: @sashkins yes java8 only.

openjdk version "1.8.0_392"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-8.392.08.1 (build 1.8.0_392-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-8.392.08.1 (build 25.392-b08, mixed mode)

Comment: @GanesanM, version [4.13.0](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2023/selenium-4-13-0-released/) is the last one that supports Java8. Try downgrading selenium or upgrading java to at least v11.

Comment: Working now with 4.13.0 selenium version and 5.6.3 WDM version. 
Thanks a lot @sashkins

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the older version of `WebDriverManager` is incorrectly resolving the current (Feb 2024) `ChromeDriver` download URL to https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/121.0.6167.184/win64/chromedriver-win64.zip

You can manually work around it it by downloading the latest [stable Chromedriver](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/) to the correct directory (e.g. `[your WDM path]\chromedriver\win64\121.0.6167.85`) and then deleting resolution.properties

However, the permanent fix is to update your [WDM to the latest version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager) (or at least [v5.5.3 as this changes where the ChromeDriver repo is](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)) - it will then work correctly, **but you must delete `[your WDM path]\resolution.properties` before the next run**, as it will have cached the incorrect version

Comment: Getting this error now

**error: cannot access org.openqa.selenium.OutputType
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
                          ^
  bad class file: /Users/username/Library/Gradle/gradle-7.5.1/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api/4.16.1/55e13a2d43a7c174ee85152a8161e9acc101de32/selenium-api-4.16.1.jar(org/openqa/selenium/OutputType.class)
    class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.**

Comment: build.gradle
implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '4.16.1'
    implementation group: 'io.github.bonigarcia', name: 'webdrivermanager', version: '5.5.3'

Answer (score 0):

Use latest WebDriverManager version 5.7.0 without scope tag. If still facing some issue please add scope tag to test in maven WebDriverManager 5.7.0 dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by manually adding an exact version of Chromedriver using WebDriverManager:

WebDriverManager.chromedriver().browserVersion("your-chromedriver-version").setup();

Replace "your-chromedriver-version" with the specific version of Chromedriver you want to use. For example, my Chrome browser version is 122.0.6261.70:

WebDriverManager.chromedriver().browserVersion("122.0.6261.69").setup();
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

This way, WebDriverManager will download and set up the specified version of Chromedriver for you.
Ensure that you use a version compatible with your Chrome browser version.
You can check the Chromedriver releases page (https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/) for the available versions.

Hope this helps!

UPDATE:
For some reason, it works now without specifying the Chrome version :
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();